# how to add percentage progress bar for asp.net web application during file download

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to add percentage progress bar for asp.net web application during file download? I am writing download code in server side not able to update progress bar.

My download code is as follows

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", totalSize.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```